# Omitting certain migration files in Flyway

Tags: database-migration, flyway

There are certain migrations that insert *a lot* of data into our production database. They slow down the integration tests and are completely not needed during the testing phase. I'd rather not solve this by boilerplate conditionals in SQL.

Is there a way to apply profiles to Flyway scripts and omit chosen migrations when necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split them out in a separate directory and configure `flyway.locations` to selectively include it.